# Get all truthy values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to get all truthy values from an array of objects:

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'string',
    val: false,
  },
  {
    name: true,
    val: [],
  }
]

const identifiers = users.map(i => Object.entries(i))
const active = identifiers.filter(function(id) {
  const t = id.map((i, k) => id[k][1])
  return t
})

console.log(active)
```

The idea of the code above at the end to use `Object.fromEntries()` and to get something like this:

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'string,
  },
  {
    name: true,
  }
]
```

At the moment i am blocked and i can't get the expected values. Who can help to get the expected result?

Comment: some serial downvoting here, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
const newData = users.map(user => {
  return Object.keys(user).reduce((obj, key) => {
    if (user[key]) { //for strict truthy, make user[key] === true
      obj[key] = user[key];
    }
    return obj;
  } ,{});
});
```

That will:

1. Perform the object filter operation on each element of the array (map).
2. Iterate over each key of the object (Object.keys(user).reduce)
3. Only add a key value pair if the value is truthy.

Note that this will return a new structure, not modify the existing one. I saw the update to the question and put a comment in the code accordingly.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote a verified answer, at least give a comment as to why this was done. It looks like it happened to all answers. I've just created an account here and I don't appreciate having this kind of hit to it for apparently no reason.

Comment: This is so true. I don't understand who did this, but we should definitely allow the community to grow by encouraging practitioner in constructive manner. Then should mention in comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create an object using **just the properties that are truthy**:

```js
const users = [{
    name: true,
    val: false,
  },
  {
    name: true,
    val: true,
  }
]

const identifiers = users.map(e => { // Map User array
  return Object.fromEntries( // return new object for every element
    Object.entries(e).filter((o) => o[1] === true) // object constructed using just truthy values by filtering object o[1] -> value
  )
});

console.log(identifiers)
```

Or a beautiful one liner:

```
const identifiers = users.map(e => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(e).filter(([_,o]) => o)));
```

Comment: how to do if my array will look like this: const users = [{
    name: true,
    val: false,
  },
  {
    name: true,
    val: [],
  }
], to get something like this: const users = [{
    name: true,
  },
  {
    name: true,
  }
]?

Comment: @Asking: please update your original question accordingly. An array, even an empty one, is generally considered as "truthy".

Comment: `!![] == true`, like `!!true == true` or `!!"test" == true`, use type checking in the filter like I've done `o[1] === true` to get not all truthy values but all booleans that are exact equal to true!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` method with `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`

```
let result = users.reduce((acc,i) => { 
                 let obj = Object.entries(i).filter(([k,v]) => v); 
                 acc.push(Object.fromEntries(obj)); 
                 return acc;  
               }, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: goo answer, but could you take a look now, i updated the question.

Comment: @Asking `users = [{
    name: 'string',
    val: false,
  },
  {
    name: true,
    val: [],
  },
  {
    name: false,
    val: true,
  }
]` what should be the expected output for this input?

Comment: i added in the question

Comment: @Asking, please check this example `users = [{     name: 'string',     val: false,   },   {     name: true,     val: [],   },   {     name: false,     val: true,   } ] what should be the expected output for this input?`. In your question you mentioned other example.

Answer (score -1):

You can decompose, filter and reconstruct the objects like this:

```js
const users = [{name:true,val:false,},{name:true,val:[],dd:0,ee:1,ff:[0,1]}],
      res = users.map(i =>
        Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(i).filter(([_,v])=>
           !Array.isArray(v)&&v || v.length)) )

console.log(res)
```